# TLS 1.0 cannot be negotiated when TLS 1.2 is enabled

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, https, webclient, tls1.2

The following code:

```
using System.Net;

namespace HttpsClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3
                                       | SecurityProtocolType.Tls
                                       | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
                                       | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
                ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback
                    += (sender, certificate, chain, errors) => true;
                var str = client.DownloadString(
                    "https://ssb.unwsp.edu/pls/banprod/twbkwbis.P_WWWLogin");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

cannot establish the connection, it ends with System.Net.WebException The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

As Wireshark capture shows, the server side refuses to use TLS 1.2 protocol.

When ServicePointManager is configured to use Ssl3 and Tls only, the connection can be successfully established.

Questions:

1. Is it true that WebClient does not support protocol version negotiation from TLS 1.2 to TLS 1.0?
2. Can I configure it somehow to force it to negotiate TLS 1.0?

Thanks

Comment: Hello, did you find solution for this problem?